# React router , routes not workin

Tags: javascript

I am tried to make a chat room application with react js,
but I have faced a problem when I tried to see just chatroom page then it's ok, but when I refresh the page then again show me the home page that mean show me both page in the chatroom page, I don't know why show me home page again,

I have tried this way:

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import TopBar from "./TopBar";
import { createBrowserHistory as createHistory } from "history";
import "./App.css";
import ChatRoomPage from "./ChatRoomPage";
const history = createHistory();

function App() {
  console.log("Working");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router history={history}>
        <TopBar />
        <Route path="/:chatRoomId" component={HomePage} />

        <Route
          path="/chatroom"
          exact
          render={(props) => <ChatRoomPage {...props} />}
        />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

any suggestion please.

Comment: If need more details code, then I will can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `react router dom` exact way

like: `import { BrowswerRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";`

then take upper the render router.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowswerRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import TopBar from "./TopBar";
import { createBrowserHistory as createHistory } from "history";
import "./App.css";
import ChatRoomPage from "./ChatRoomPage";
const history = createHistory();

function App() {
  console.log("Working");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router history={history}>
        <TopBar />
        <Switch>

         <Route
          path="/chatroom"
          exact
          render={(props) => <ChatRoomPage {...props} />}
        />

        <Route path="/:chatRoomId" component={HomePage} />

        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```